# read data from json file and insert into mongodb (meteorjs)

Tags: javascript, json, meteor

I have a file that contains data in json format.

```
{
"channelName" : "practice",
"startDate" : ISODate("2017-07-22T06:29:35.681Z"),
"endDate" : ISODate("2017-08-22T06:29:35.681Z")
}
```

Above is the file format. Filename is test.json. I want to read it at my server side and insert into db. I tried using Assets.getText but failed reading the file in json format. Following is the code i wrote

```
Assets.getText('channelTestData.json', function(err, res){
// var test = JSON.parse(res);
// console.log('tets : ' + test);
Channel.insert(res);
// Channel.save(res);
});
```

If i use JSON.parse or EJSON.parse, it throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dates are invalid JSON. You probably get this error:

```
Exception in callback of getAsset SyntaxError: Unexpected token I
```

You can find valid JSON data types here([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example)). Your JSON file should looks like:

```
{
  "channelName" : "practice",
  "startDate" : "2017-07-21T11:59:26.040Z",
  "endDate" : "2017-07-21T11:59:26.040Z"
}
```

If you are creating new Data object you can use below code to get valid JSON which won't throw errors.

```
new Date().toJSON()
```

---

Also is it worth to mention that files you would like to get using `#getText()` should be in the `private` directory in your app folder. More about this topic can be found in the [Meteor docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/assets.html)

Comment: You can then convert it to a date using string - `new Date('2017-07-21T11:59:26.040Z')`.